# scrolling issue while adding heavy file in UIWebView in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, pdf, webview

I am having a problem about webView and Pdf ..

When I load a pdf file that is having 10 mb size ..

the file takes a lot time to load and my Pdf also dosnt scroll well ...

can anyone tell me what can be the issue?

here is the code ...

```
  if ([resource.resource_type isEqualToString:@"pdf"] ) {
    tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",resource.resource_link];
    type = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pdf"];

}
else {
    tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",resource.resource_link];
    type = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jpg"];

}


      NSArray *myArray = [tempStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[myArray objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[myArray objectAtIndex:1]];

        NSLog(@"array elemt :%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"array elemt 1 :%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:1]);

        NSLog(@"path is :%@",path);

        if (isFirstTime) {
            NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
            [docWebView loadRequest:request];
            isFirstTime = NO;
        }
        if(isLandscape == NO){
            docWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 768.0, 960.0);
        }
        else {
            docWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 1024.0, 700.0);
        }
        [self.view addSubview:docWebView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:activity];
```

Answer (score 0):

10 Mb is a large file especially if its contains images ... try to open it with iBooks and see how much time it will take .. the problem may not be with your code, i think its in the file size.